# Import from tt_news with additional fields in tt_news and news (TYPO3 8 LTS)

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-news

import from tt_news in TYPO3 8 LTS with actual news and news_ttnewsimport is working fine. But we had some individual fields in tt_news and i want to import theese fields too in individuel fields in news.

So i made a new extension which extends news with individual fields. It is working fine: i can edit them in the backend and print content in the frontend.

Then i modified getImportData() in TTNewsNewsDataProviderService of news_ttnewsimport and added my new fields. The content of the individual fields of tt_news is fetched, i controlled it with a log-file. But the content was not written in the database ... I controlled the getter and setter in my configuration of news but all seems correct.

After some debugging i found that all commands which write the content in news are hardcoded in news/Classes/Domain/Service/NewsImportService.php:

```
$news->setAuthor($importItem['author']);
```

After adding my fields all works:

```
$news->setMyNewField($importItem['my_new_field']);
```

So my problem is fixed ... well some how: it seems dirty to change a class of an extension in order to handle individual fields.

Is there a correct possibility to make the import work with individual fields, without patching news?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 7 of tx_news i found the answer of my question ... i don't know wether it exists in older versions but in 7.1 it is possible to use a signal slot for this task:

[link to the manual: Prehydrate slot](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/DeveloperManual/ExtendNews/ImportService/Index.html?highlight=tt_news_import#)